# WatiN doubleclick not working in IE9

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-9, watin

I'm using watin testing tool for our asp.net mvc 3 web application.

The same test works for ie 8 but not for ie9.

```
Element element = frame.ElementWithTag("td", Find.ByText("a14"));
element.DoubleClick();
```

Any Idea? or workaround to simulate doubleclick in ie 9.

Comment: did you get anywhere with this, run into same issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a workaround, if you have jquery available on your page you could do as I did:

```
row.DomContainer.Eval(string.Format("$('#{0}').dblclick();", row.Id));
```

I had tried several different variations on the ondblclick event, which WatiN uses itself ([line 470 of Core.Element](http://watin.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/watin/trunk/src/Core/Element.cs?revision=1203&view=markup)), to no avail.

Comment: With the help of @dove's answer, I end up with: Browser.Eval(string.Format("$('#{0}').dblclick();", id));